# DRF check if an object already exist in DB when receiving a request

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have products defined by their Name and Location. Each product has a unique pair of Name/Location.

I'm writing a view to be able to create a product and I would like to first check if it exists in DB.
If yes then keep the ID somewhere to return it to my front app.
If no then create it and get the ID also.

From my research, overriding the perform_create method should be the solution but I can't figure out how to.

Any help would be appreciated.

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from main.views import product_view

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^products/$', product_view.ProductCreate.as_view()),
    url(r'^products/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', product_view.ProductDetail.as_view()),
]
```

**product_view.py**

```
from rest_framework import generics
from rest_framework import permissions

from main.models import Product
from main.serializers import ProductSerializer


class ProductCreate(generics.CreateAPIView):
    """
    Create a new product.
    """

    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)

    serializer_class = ProductSerializer
    queryset = Product.objects.all()

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
    if serializer.is_valid():
        product_name = serializer.validated_data['product_name']
        product_location = serializer.validated_data['product_location']

        if product_name != '':
            product_list = Product.objects.filter(
                product_name=product_name, product_location=product_location)

            if not product_list:
                product = create_product(product_name, product_location)
            else:
                product = product_list[0]

            serializer = ProductSerializer(product)
            return Response(serializer.data)
        else:
            return Response(data={'message': 'Empty product_name'}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
    else:
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)


class ProductDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateAPIView):
    """
    Retrieve, update or delete a product.
    """

    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)

    serializer_class = ProductSerializer
    queryset = Product.objects.all()
```

**serializer.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from rest_framework import serializers
from main.models import Product


class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ('id',
              'product_name',
              'product_shop',
              'product_url',
              'product_img',
              'product_location')
```

**EDIT**

product model :

```
class Product(models.Model):
    product_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    product_shop = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    product_url = models.CharField(max_length=400, blank=False)
    product_img = models.CharField(max_length=400, blank=True)
    product_location = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False)
    product_creation_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)
    productgroup = models.ForeignKey(ProductGroup, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return '#' + str(self.pk) + ' ' + self.product_name + ' (' + self.product_shop + ')'
```

A product is automatically created depending on its name and location. A specific function is handling the creation and fulfill the data.

The result I get in my front app is missing some data using this code.
Here is an example using httpie :

- Request : http POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/products/ product_name="Product test" product_location="Loc1" product_img="www.myimg.com"
- Result : 
  HTTP/1.0 201 Created
  Allow: POST, OPTIONS
  Content-Length: 247
  Content-Type: application/json
  Date: Thu, 08 Mar 2018 13:58:18 GMT
  Server: WSGIServer/0.2 CPython/3.5.3
  Vary: Accept
  X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN

{
    "product_location": "Loc1",
    "product_name": "Product test",
    "product_img": "www.myimg.com"
}

In DB the product exists and has values for product_shop and product_url, and of course has an ID.

**EDIT 2**

I did some more test and logged as many things as possible.

Here is my perform_create function and the results from the logger :

```
def perform_create(self, serializer):
        if serializer.is_valid():
            product_name = serializer.validated_data['product_name']
            product_location = serializer.validated_data['product_location']

            if product_name != '':
                product_list = Product.objects.filter(
                    product_name=product_name, product_location=product_location)

                if not product_list:
                    product = create_product(product_name, product_location)
                else:
                    product = product_list[0]

                logger.info('product id : ' + str(product.id)) # Generated automatically
                logger.info('product name : ' + product.product_name) # From the request
                logger.info('product url : ' + product.product_url) # Generated by my create_product function

                serializer = ProductSerializer(product)

                logger.info('serializer.data['id'] : ' + str(serializer.data['id']))
                return Response(serializer.data)
            else:
                return Response(data={'message': 'Empty product_name'}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
        else:
            return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Here are the results and they are good :

*product id : 3713*

*product name : Product 1*

*product url : /products/Product1/...*

*serializer.data['id'] : 3713*

In the result of the request I now have only the product_url and the product_location....

Is there any other way to achieve what I want?

Comment: Does `create_product` return product instance?

Comment: Yes it does and t answer your previous question, when I request a product that already exists I return its instance and I don't create anything in db has wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so I solved my problem NOT using perform_create. I came back to an easy APIView and defined the POST method as wanted. Works perfectly now.

```
class ProductCreate(APIView):
    """
    Create a new product.
    """

    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)

    def post(cls, request, format=None):
        serializer = ProductSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
           ............
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to check is serializer is valid at first. Then you can call serializer.save() to create new object, or just create new serializer object and pass to it already existing product:

```
def perform_create(self, serializer):
    if serializer.is_valid():
        product_name = serializer.validated_data['product_name']
        product_location = serializer.validated_data['product_location']

        if product_name != '':
            product_list = Product.objects.filter(
                product_name=product_name, product_location=product_location)

            if not product_list:
                product = serializer.save()
            else:
                product = product_list[0]
                serializer = ProductSerializer(product)
            return Response(serializer.data)   
        else:
            return Response(data={'message': 'Empty product_name'},
                        status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
    else:
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

If serializer's data is not valid you have to return `serializer.errors`.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, it works well but I have some questions. First, I commented the line "product = serializer.save()" because I do not create my Product from the data sent by the user, is there any problem doing this? Second, I would like to return the Product ID to the front app, how can I do that?

Comment: @Alk no, it shouldnt be any problems if you save product with custom method. As for the second question id should be part of returned data if you have id in serializer's fields: fields = ('id','product_name','product_location'). If you need to return only id. You can directly put it to the response: return Response({'id': product.id})

Comment: I do have a return but it only contains the name and location. In DB my product is created and has an ID. Here is the code "serializer = ProductSerializer(product)  return Response(serializer.data)". Any idea?

Comment: @Alk can you add product model?

Comment: I updated my question with the code. I updated the serializer in the mean time.

Comment: @Alk I cannot see any problems. With this code id should return also.

Comment: I wish it does :) I updated the question to shox you the request and results.

Comment: @Alk and in case if you send existing product_name and location? Is it the same? Can you add your current view code and create product function?

Comment: The view is up to date. I can't give you the create_product function as it depends on many other functions. Basically it goes in DB and find info about the location and the product then compile them together to generate an image with logo, give an internal url access etc... In DB the Product is good and I can display it's full data while going directly through the url "/products/ID". I saw something that might help : if I add the product_url in my request, it is returned with the value provided not the generated one (that is also in DB). Seems like the data returned are the one sent only.

Comment: Thanks for this answer! I was looking for an example to return automatically serializer errors...I did not know that I should use `serializer.errors`

Answer (score -1):

### DRF Check if an object already exist or not and perform an action if it exists

> Example: if you do not want an user to like the same post twice, then follow
> the steps below

***Note:- This post is an example of viewsets.ModelViewSet, You can use the below create() method to check for an object if it exists already or not, also can perform an action if it does exist, many people confused whether to use perform_create() or create(), Well straight on point i would say with this use case use create(),***

```
class PostLikeViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
queryset = PostLike.objects.all()
serializer_class = PostLikeSerializer
pagination_class = CustomPagination
filter_backends = [filters.OrderingFilter,filters.SearchFilter]
ordering_fields = ["created_at"]
ordering = ["-created_at"]
search_fields = ["post_id","like_id","user_id"]

**def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    if PostLike.objects.filter(post_id=request.data['post_id'],user_id=request.data['user_id']):
        return Response({"Error" : "You've already liked this post!"},status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
    else:
        return super().create(request, *args, **kwargs)**
```

### **Thanks for looking at this, let me know in the comments if you stuck anywhere :)**